# How to identify the health of the new disks after installing new OS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux, fsck

We want to create some sanity about the health check of the disks.

For example, we installed around 50 Linux Red Hat machines (Red Hat version 7.2). 
Each machine have around 7 disks (disks can be identified by lsblk).

So, how do we identify the health check of the disks on each machine?

Comment: What specifically is the "health" you want to identify? And you've got 7 physical hard disks / ssd's on each machine?

Answer (score 0):

At the basic level install smarttools, if it's not already on the system. Then you can use smartctl to view the status of your disks.

`smartctl -a /dev/sda`

Smart will even monitor your system and send you an email if one of your disks starts to go bad, so you can proactively replace it before it completely fails.